# Why do I recieve an 'undefined local variable or method' message for any string i write on Mac's TextEdit?

Tags: ruby, macos, sublimetext

I'm trying to learn to code, starting with ruby. While using TextEdit I was able to run numerical code, but any variation of `puts "text"` returned the error message of

> undefined local variable or method '"text"' for main:Object (NameError).

I used another text editor and it worked just fine. Can anyone help me understand what went wrong? Thank you!

I'm now using Sublime Text instead of TextEdit.

Comment: Use Scite editor, It will allow you to run by pressing F5. If you want to use IDE, then RubyMine.

Comment: Just being curious: Why are you using a **text editor** to execute a Ruby program? I would simply use Ruby from the command line. If you just want to try out quickly a few Ruby commands, use `irb`.

Comment: Walking into this blind, I started using the text editor because the guide suggested it. I did check out `irb`, and it was fun- thanks! But isn't a text editor better to practice using different commands in tandem? @user1934428

Comment: Don't know. Never tried it. For me, an editor is used to write programs, store them into a file, and execute them from a  command line. I guess everyone has a different approach to programming. However, note that irb by default writes a transscript of your session to a history file, when you exit it; hence you can retrieve your experiments and paste them into your editor, when needed.

Comment: Okay! There has been a misunderstanding here. I'm not using the text editor to run the program, I'm doing exactly what you said- write the program in the editor and then execute from the command line. @user1934428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common source of these errors is using an editor which replaces the "plain" quote characters `"`  `'` with typographic quotes. Your original code

```
puts "text"
```

may thus be replaced by your editor with

```
puts “text”
```

Ruby always requires the "plain" quoting characters with string literals however. When using other characters, Ruby assumes that you want to  call a method called `“text”` and fails accordingly as you didn't define such a method.

In the end, it is usually a good idea to use an editor which is geared for code editing (such as Sublime, VisualStudio Code, Textmate, Nova, or others) rather than an editor geared towards text editing (such as TextEdit, Pages, Word, ...), specifically to avoid such issues.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the plain vs. typographic quotes issue, this really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

TextEdit on a Mac defaults to "Rich Text", which embeds information about font choices and size, bold/italics, underlining, kerning and spacing, etc. You can use it to edit code, but to do so you will need to go to the `Format` menu and select `Make Plain Text`. That will remove all the embedded formatting bytes.

While that will work, the experience will not be nearly as pleasant as using a programmer's text editor which helps with indentation, syntax coloring, and (usually) provides tools to compile or run your code. MacOS ships with vi/vim and pico, which both work from the command-line. While vi is powerful, it has a very steep learning curve. Pico is minimalist but shows available commands at the bottom of the window. Lots of other fine choices can be easily downloaded. Some are free, some require payment. Your relationship with an editor very much revolves around your personal taste, and you'll spend a lot of time in whatever environment you pick, so I recommend trying several and seeing what suits you personally - sort of like picking shoes.

Comment: If using TextEdit I also _strongly_ suggest `Edit` -> `Spelling and Grammar` -> uncheck `Check Spelling While Typing`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take your advice and work with different editors over time to see which one suits me best.